# How to create one-line layout where long string gets truncated 'inline'?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a one-lined 2-column layout. The first column should display a potentially lengthy string, truncated so that it fits in the one-line layout. Similary to [How to Create Automatically Expanding Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119492/how-to-create-automatically-expanding-block) I did the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Lengthy string</div>
  <div class="right">Short</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

In contrast to this solution I would like the right column not to be on the far right but directly behind the content of the left column.

Any ideas how this could be done?

EDIT:

Example to clarify what I mean with 'directly behind':

'Lengthy string' may be a category in an online shop, 'Short' may be a number of available items in this category. Since category name + number may be wider than the width of their container the category names might need to be truncated, e.g.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Electronic equipment for consumer</div>
  <div class="right">(599)</div>
</div>
```

should be rendered as

```
Eletronic equipment... (599)
```

With directly behind I mean that for short category names, say 'Books', this should look like

```
Books (29)
```

and not like

```
Books             (29)
```

Comment: "directly behind the content of the left column" or directly **next** to the content of the left column?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive I understand what you mean by "directly behind", but I think this may be what you're after:

```
.left {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline;
 }

 .right {
   float: right;
   display: inline;
 }
```

Making the `<div>`'s inline will eliminate the need for floats, generally making your life easier.

Comment: If left contains a long string then the width of left (which is not specified explicitly) gets too big: left and right do not fit on one line anymore.

Comment: I assume you're not setting a width because you want the div to expand with the content...to a point.  Are you opposed to setting a `max-width` property on `.left`?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if this worked without any explicit widths and max-widths. See also my updated question.

Comment: Alternatively, you could truncate the `lengthly string` before sending it out to the client, ensuring that the string itself would never exceed some limit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign a fixed width or, if your browser supports that, a maximum width for this to work.

The way you defined it right now, the browser is free to make the left element as wide as it wants.

You should also consider to float `left` on the left and not float `right`. Or use `display: inline` for both and don't float anything.

Comment: I think the way I defined it right now, the browser makes the left element only as wide so that left and right fits in one line. As soon as I do a `float: left` or `display: inline` the auto-expanding effect of `overflow: hidden` is away.

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS creates a one-line 2 column layout

```
#wrapper { display: table }
#wrapper > div { display: table-cell; }
#wrapper > div:first-child { min-width: 200px; /*Using min-width allows expantion */ }
#wrapper > div:last-child { min-width: 200px; }
#wrapper > div p { white-space:nowrap; } //One line text

<div id="wrapper">
  <div><!-- Left menu? --></div>
  <div><p>very long text very long text etc..</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He wants the very long text in the *left* column